# MP4Box does not concatenate videos

Tags: video, mp4box

I have problem with MP4Box, can't concatenate videos in one video. I get out.mp4 file (~103 MB) but omxplayer can not play it. I have 6 very simple .mp4 videos and I want them to merge in one video. Until now, I was able to do that with command, without any problems:

```
MP4Box -cat Awards\ -\ Recognitions\ Screens\ Video.mp4 -cat Cornaro\ USLUGE\ video1.mp4 -cat Cornaro\ USLUGE\ video1.mp4 -cat DIOCLETIANS_BREAKFAST.mp4 -cat FLAVOURS_OF_DALMATIA.mp4 -cat Prognoza.mp4 -cat Restaurants\ -\ Bars\ 2016.mp4 -cat WineHappyHour3.mp4 -new out.mp4
```

but now omxplayer (also vlc) can not play out.mp4 video. Here is mediainfo output for every one of 6 videos:

```
General
Complete name                            : Awards - Recognitions Screens Video.mp4
Format                                   : MPEG-4
Format profile                           : Base Media
Codec ID                                 : isom
File size                                : 16.8 MiB
Duration                                 : 45s 379ms
Overall bit rate                         : 3 114 Kbps
Writing application                      : Lavf55.33.101

Video
ID                                       : 1
Format                                   : AVC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Video Codec
Format profile                           : Main@L5.1
Format settings, CABAC                   : Yes
Format settings, ReFrames                : 3 frames
Codec ID                                 : avc1
Codec ID/Info                            : Advanced Video Coding
Duration                                 : 45s 379ms
Bit rate                                 : 3 000 Kbps
Width                                    : 1 920 pixels
Height                                   : 1 080 pixels
Display aspect ratio                     : 16:9
Frame rate mode                          : Constant
Frame rate                               : 29.970 fps
Color space                              : YUV
Chroma subsampling                       : 4:2:0
Bit depth                                : 8 bits
Scan type                                : Progressive
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)                       : 0.048
Stream size                              : 16.8 MiB (100%)
Writing library                          : x264 core 142 r2389 956c8d8
Encoding settings                        : cabac=1 / ref=1 / deblock=1:0:0 / analyse=0x1:0 / me=dia / subme=2 / psy=1 / psy_rd=1.00:0.00 / mixed_ref=0 / me_range=16 / chroma_me=1 / trellis=0 / 8x8dct=0 / cqm=0 / deadzone=21,11 / fast_pskip=1 / chroma_qp_offset=0 / threads=6 / lookahead_threads=2 / sliced_threads=0 / nr=0 / decimate=1 / interlaced=0 / bluray_compat=0 / constrained_intra=0 / bframes=3 / b_pyramid=1 / b_adapt=1 / b_bias=0 / direct=1 / weightb=1 / open_gop=0 / weightp=2 / keyint=250 / keyint_min=25 / scenecut=40 / intra_refresh=0 / rc_lookahead=40 / rc=abr / mbtree=1 / bitrate=3000 / ratetol=1.0 / qcomp=0.60 / qpmin=0 / qpmax=69 / qpstep=4 / ip_ratio=1.40 / aq=1:1.00
Language                                 : English



General
Complete name                            : Cornaro USLUGE video1.mp4
Format                                   : MPEG-4
Format profile                           : Base Media
Codec ID                                 : isom
File size                                : 22.8 MiB
Duration                                 : 1mn 13s
Overall bit rate                         : 2 624 Kbps
Writing application                      : Lavf55.33.101

Video
ID                                       : 1
Format                                   : AVC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Video Codec
Format profile                           : Main@L5.1
Format settings, CABAC                   : Yes
Format settings, ReFrames                : 3 frames
Codec ID                                 : avc1
Codec ID/Info                            : Advanced Video Coding
Duration                                 : 1mn 13s
Bit rate                                 : 2 621 Kbps
Nominal bit rate                         : 3 000 Kbps
Width                                    : 1 920 pixels
Height                                   : 1 080 pixels
Display aspect ratio                     : 16:9
Frame rate mode                          : Constant
Frame rate                               : 29.970 fps
Color space                              : YUV
Chroma subsampling                       : 4:2:0
Bit depth                                : 8 bits
Scan type                                : Progressive
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)                       : 0.042
Stream size                              : 22.8 MiB (100%)
Writing library                          : x264 core 142 r2389 956c8d8
Encoding settings                        : cabac=1 / ref=1 / deblock=1:0:0 / analyse=0x1:0 / me=dia / subme=2 / psy=1 / psy_rd=1.00:0.00 / mixed_ref=0 / me_range=16 / chroma_me=1 / trellis=0 / 8x8dct=0 / cqm=0 / deadzone=21,11 / fast_pskip=1 / chroma_qp_offset=0 / threads=6 / lookahead_threads=2 / sliced_threads=0 / nr=0 / decimate=1 / interlaced=0 / bluray_compat=0 / constrained_intra=0 / bframes=3 / b_pyramid=1 / b_adapt=1 / b_bias=0 / direct=1 / weightb=1 / open_gop=0 / weightp=2 / keyint=250 / keyint_min=25 / scenecut=40 / intra_refresh=0 / rc_lookahead=40 / rc=abr / mbtree=1 / bitrate=3000 / ratetol=1.0 / qcomp=0.60 / qpmin=0 / qpmax=69 / qpstep=4 / ip_ratio=1.40 / aq=1:1.00
Language                                 : English



General
Complete name                            : DIOCLETIANS_BREAKFAST.mp4
Format                                   : MPEG-4
Format profile                           : Base Media
Codec ID                                 : isom
File size                                : 11.6 MiB
Duration                                 : 33s 0ms
Overall bit rate                         : 2 950 Kbps
Writing application                      : Lavf55.33.101

Video
ID                                       : 1
Format                                   : AVC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Video Codec
Format profile                           : Main@L5.1
Format settings, CABAC                   : Yes
Format settings, ReFrames                : 3 frames
Codec ID                                 : avc1
Codec ID/Info                            : Advanced Video Coding
Duration                                 : 33s 0ms
Bit rate                                 : 3 000 Kbps
Width                                    : 1 920 pixels
Height                                   : 1 080 pixels
Display aspect ratio                     : 16:9
Frame rate mode                          : Constant
Frame rate                               : 29.970 fps
Color space                              : YUV
Chroma subsampling                       : 4:2:0
Bit depth                                : 8 bits
Scan type                                : Progressive
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)                       : 0.048
Stream size                              : 11.6 MiB (100%)
Writing library                          : x264 core 142 r2389 956c8d8
Encoding settings                        : cabac=1 / ref=1 / deblock=1:0:0 / analyse=0x1:0 / me=dia / subme=2 / psy=1 / psy_rd=1.00:0.00 / mixed_ref=0 / me_range=16 / chroma_me=1 / trellis=0 / 8x8dct=0 / cqm=0 / deadzone=21,11 / fast_pskip=1 / chroma_qp_offset=0 / threads=6 / lookahead_threads=2 / sliced_threads=0 / nr=0 / decimate=1 / interlaced=0 / bluray_compat=0 / constrained_intra=0 / bframes=3 / b_pyramid=1 / b_adapt=1 / b_bias=0 / direct=1 / weightb=1 / open_gop=0 / weightp=2 / keyint=250 / keyint_min=25 / scenecut=40 / intra_refresh=0 / rc_lookahead=40 / rc=abr / mbtree=1 / bitrate=3000 / ratetol=1.0 / qcomp=0.60 / qpmin=0 / qpmax=69 / qpstep=4 / ip_ratio=1.40 / aq=1:1.00
Language                                 : English



General
Complete name                            : FLAVOURS_OF_DALMATIA.mp4
Format                                   : MPEG-4
Format profile                           : Base Media
Codec ID                                 : isom
File size                                : 11.4 MiB
Duration                                 : 33s 0ms
Overall bit rate                         : 2 891 Kbps
Writing application                      : Lavf55.33.101

Video
ID                                       : 1
Format                                   : AVC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Video Codec
Format profile                           : Main@L5.1
Format settings, CABAC                   : Yes
Format settings, ReFrames                : 3 frames
Codec ID                                 : avc1
Codec ID/Info                            : Advanced Video Coding
Duration                                 : 33s 0ms
Bit rate                                 : 3 000 Kbps
Width                                    : 1 920 pixels
Height                                   : 1 080 pixels
Display aspect ratio                     : 16:9
Frame rate mode                          : Constant
Frame rate                               : 29.970 fps
Color space                              : YUV
Chroma subsampling                       : 4:2:0
Bit depth                                : 8 bits
Scan type                                : Progressive
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)                       : 0.048
Stream size                              : 11.4 MiB (100%)
Writing library                          : x264 core 142 r2389 956c8d8
Encoding settings                        : cabac=1 / ref=1 / deblock=1:0:0 / analyse=0x1:0 / me=dia / subme=2 / psy=1 / psy_rd=1.00:0.00 / mixed_ref=0 / me_range=16 / chroma_me=1 / trellis=0 / 8x8dct=0 / cqm=0 / deadzone=21,11 / fast_pskip=1 / chroma_qp_offset=0 / threads=6 / lookahead_threads=2 / sliced_threads=0 / nr=0 / decimate=1 / interlaced=0 / bluray_compat=0 / constrained_intra=0 / bframes=3 / b_pyramid=1 / b_adapt=1 / b_bias=0 / direct=1 / weightb=1 / open_gop=0 / weightp=2 / keyint=250 / keyint_min=25 / scenecut=40 / intra_refresh=0 / rc_lookahead=40 / rc=abr / mbtree=1 / bitrate=3000 / ratetol=1.0 / qcomp=0.60 / qpmin=0 / qpmax=69 / qpstep=4 / ip_ratio=1.40 / aq=1:1.00
Language                                 : English



General
Complete name                            : Prognoza.mp4
Format                                   : MPEG-4
Format profile                           : Base Media
Codec ID                                 : isom
File size                                : 3.27 MiB
Duration                                 : 10s 44ms
Overall bit rate                         : 2 733 Kbps
Writing application                      : Lavf55.33.101

Video
ID                                       : 1
Format                                   : AVC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Video Codec
Format profile                           : Main@L5.1
Format settings, CABAC                   : Yes
Format settings, ReFrames                : 3 frames
Codec ID                                 : avc1
Codec ID/Info                            : Advanced Video Coding
Duration                                 : 10s 44ms
Bit rate                                 : 2 730 Kbps
Nominal bit rate                         : 3 000 Kbps
Width                                    : 1 920 pixels
Height                                   : 1 080 pixels
Display aspect ratio                     : 16:9
Frame rate mode                          : Constant
Frame rate                               : 29.970 fps
Color space                              : YUV
Chroma subsampling                       : 4:2:0
Bit depth                                : 8 bits
Scan type                                : Progressive
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)                       : 0.044
Stream size                              : 3.27 MiB (100%)
Writing library                          : x264 core 142 r2389 956c8d8
Encoding settings                        : cabac=1 / ref=1 / deblock=1:0:0 / analyse=0x1:0 / me=dia / subme=2 / psy=1 / psy_rd=1.00:0.00 / mixed_ref=0 / me_range=16 / chroma_me=1 / trellis=0 / 8x8dct=0 / cqm=0 / deadzone=21,11 / fast_pskip=1 / chroma_qp_offset=0 / threads=6 / lookahead_threads=2 / sliced_threads=0 / nr=0 / decimate=1 / interlaced=0 / bluray_compat=0 / constrained_intra=0 / bframes=3 / b_pyramid=1 / b_adapt=1 / b_bias=0 / direct=1 / weightb=1 / open_gop=0 / weightp=2 / keyint=250 / keyint_min=25 / scenecut=40 / intra_refresh=0 / rc_lookahead=40 / rc=abr / mbtree=1 / bitrate=3000 / ratetol=1.0 / qcomp=0.60 / qpmin=0 / qpmax=69 / qpstep=4 / ip_ratio=1.40 / aq=1:1.00
Language                                 : English`



General
Complete name                            : Restaurants - Bars 2016.mp4
Format                                   : MPEG-4
Format profile                           : Base Media
Codec ID                                 : isom
File size                                : 33.4 MiB
Duration                                 : 1mn 35s
Overall bit rate                         : 2 929 Kbps
Writing application                      : Lavf55.33.101

Video
ID                                       : 1
Format                                   : AVC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Video Codec
Format profile                           : Main@L5.1
Format settings, CABAC                   : Yes
Format settings, ReFrames                : 3 frames
Codec ID                                 : avc1
Codec ID/Info                            : Advanced Video Coding
Duration                                 : 1mn 35s
Bit rate                                 : 3 000 Kbps
Width                                    : 1 920 pixels
Height                                   : 1 080 pixels
Display aspect ratio                     : 16:9
Frame rate mode                          : Constant
Frame rate                               : 29.970 fps
Color space                              : YUV
Chroma subsampling                       : 4:2:0
Bit depth                                : 8 bits
Scan type                                : Progressive
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)                       : 0.048
Stream size                              : 33.4 MiB (100%)
Writing library                          : x264 core 142 r2389 956c8d8
Encoding settings                        : cabac=1 / ref=1 / deblock=1:0:0 / analyse=0x1:0 / me=dia / subme=2 / psy=1 / psy_rd=1.00:0.00 / mixed_ref=0 / me_range=16 / chroma_me=1 / trellis=0 / 8x8dct=0 / cqm=0 / deadzone=21,11 / fast_pskip=1 / chroma_qp_offset=0 / threads=6 / lookahead_threads=2 / sliced_threads=0 / nr=0 / decimate=1 / interlaced=0 / bluray_compat=0 / constrained_intra=0 / bframes=3 / b_pyramid=1 / b_adapt=1 / b_bias=0 / direct=1 / weightb=1 / open_gop=0 / weightp=2 / keyint=250 / keyint_min=25 / scenecut=40 / intra_refresh=0 / rc_lookahead=40 / rc=abr / mbtree=1 / bitrate=3000 / ratetol=1.0 / qcomp=0.60 / qpmin=0 / qpmax=69 / qpstep=4 / ip_ratio=1.40 / aq=1:1.00
Language                                 : English



General
Complete name                            : WineHappyHour3.mp4
Format                                   : MPEG-4
Format profile                           : Base Media
Codec ID                                 : isom
File size                                : 4.10 MiB
Duration                                 : 13s 581ms
Overall bit rate                         : 2 533 Kbps
Writing application                      : Lavf55.33.101

Video
ID                                       : 1
Format                                   : AVC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Video Codec
Format profile                           : Main@L5.1
Format settings, CABAC                   : Yes
Format settings, ReFrames                : 3 frames
Codec ID                                 : avc1
Codec ID/Info                            : Advanced Video Coding
Duration                                 : 13s 581ms
Bit rate                                 : 2 530 Kbps
Nominal bit rate                         : 3 000 Kbps
Width                                    : 1 920 pixels
Height                                   : 1 080 pixels
Display aspect ratio                     : 16:9
Frame rate mode                          : Constant
Frame rate                               : 29.970 fps
Color space                              : YUV
Chroma subsampling                       : 4:2:0
Bit depth                                : 8 bits
Scan type                                : Progressive
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)                       : 0.041
Stream size                              : 4.10 MiB (100%)
Writing library                          : x264 core 142 r2389 956c8d8
Encoding settings                        : cabac=1 / ref=1 / deblock=1:0:0 / analyse=0x1:0 / me=dia / subme=2 / psy=1 / psy_rd=1.00:0.00 / mixed_ref=0 / me_range=16 / chroma_me=1 / trellis=0 / 8x8dct=0 / cqm=0 / deadzone=21,11 / fast_pskip=1 / chroma_qp_offset=0 / threads=6 / lookahead_threads=2 / sliced_threads=0 / nr=0 / decimate=1 / interlaced=0 / bluray_compat=0 / constrained_intra=0 / bframes=3 / b_pyramid=1 / b_adapt=1 / b_bias=0 / direct=1 / weightb=1 / open_gop=0 / weightp=2 / keyint=250 / keyint_min=25 / scenecut=40 / intra_refresh=0 / rc_lookahead=40 / rc=abr / mbtree=1 / bitrate=3000 / ratetol=1.0 / qcomp=0.60 / qpmin=0 / qpmax=69 / qpstep=4 / ip_ratio=1.40 / aq=1:1.00
Language                                 : English
```

So all 6 videos have good mediainfo output but anways I tried executing command to test without 1 video (one by one), and then merging them, but same result.  I get strange command line output when I execute mp4box command:

```
Appending file Awards - Recognitions Screens Video.mp4
No suitable destination track found - creating new one (type vide)
Appending file Cornaro USLUGE video1.mp4         
Appending file Cornaro USLUGE video1.mp4         
No suitable destination track found - creating new one (type vide)
Appending file DIOCLETIANS_BREAKFAST.mp4         
Appending file FLAVOURS_OF_DALMATIA.mp4          
Appending file Prognoza.mp4                      
Appending file Restaurants - Bars 2016.mp4       
No suitable destination track found - creating new one (type vide)
Appending file WineHappyHour3.mp4                
Saving out.mp4: 0.500 secs Interleaving
```

Here is mediainfo for out.mp4 video:

```
General
Complete name                            : out.mp4
Format                                   : MPEG-4
Format profile                           : Base Media
Codec ID                                 : isom
File size                                : 126 MiB
Duration                                 : 4mn 50s
Overall bit rate                         : 3 651 Kbps
Encoded date                             : UTC 2016-06-10 15:32:13
Tagged date                              : UTC 2016-06-10 15:32:13

Video #1
ID                                       : 1
Format                                   : avc3
Codec ID                                 : avc3
Duration                                 : 1mn 58s
Bit rate                                 : 2 809 Kbps
Width                                    : 1 920 pixels
Height                                   : 1 080 pixels
Display aspect ratio                     : 16:9
Frame rate mode                          : Constant
Frame rate                               : 29.970 fps
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)                       : 0.045
Stream size                              : 39.6 MiB (31%)
Language                                 : English
Tagged date                              : UTC 2016-06-10 15:32:15

Video #2
ID                                       : 2
Format                                   : AVC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Video Codec
Format profile                           : Main@L5.1
Format settings, CABAC                   : Yes
Format settings, ReFrames                : 3 frames
Codec ID                                 : avc1
Codec ID/Info                            : Advanced Video Coding
Duration                                 : 4mn 41s
Source duration                          : 3mn 28s
Bit rate                                 : 2 143 Kbps
Nominal bit rate                         : 3 000 Kbps
Width                                    : 1 920 pixels
Height                                   : 1 080 pixels
Display aspect ratio                     : 16:9
Frame rate mode                          : Variable
Frame rate                               : 23.432 fps
Minimum frame rate                       : 0.022 fps
Maximum frame rate                       : 29.970 fps
Color space                              : YUV
Chroma subsampling                       : 4:2:0
Bit depth                                : 8 bits
Scan type                                : Progressive
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)                       : 0.044
Stream size                              : 53.1 MiB (42%)
Source stream size                       : 53.1 MiB (42%)
Writing library                          : x264 core 142 r2389 956c8d8
Encoding settings                        : cabac=1 / ref=1 / deblock=1:0:0 / analyse=0x1:0 / me=dia / subme=2 / psy=1 / psy_rd=1.00:0.00 / mixed_ref=0 / me_range=16 / chroma_me=1 / trellis=0 / 8x8dct=0 / cqm=0 / deadzone=21,11 / fast_pskip=1 / chroma_qp_offset=0 / threads=6 / lookahead_threads=2 / sliced_threads=0 / nr=0 / decimate=1 / interlaced=0 / bluray_compat=0 / constrained_intra=0 / bframes=3 / b_pyramid=1 / b_adapt=1 / b_bias=0 / direct=1 / weightb=1 / open_gop=0 / weightp=2 / keyint=250 / keyint_min=25 / scenecut=40 / intra_refresh=0 / rc_lookahead=40 / rc=abr / mbtree=1 / bitrate=3000 / ratetol=1.0 / qcomp=0.60 / qpmin=0 / qpmax=69 / qpstep=4 / ip_ratio=1.40 / aq=1:1.00
Language                                 : English
Tagged date                              : UTC 2016-06-10 15:32:15

Video #3
ID                                       : 3
Format                                   : AVC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Video Codec
Format profile                           : Main@L5.1
Format settings, CABAC                   : Yes
Format settings, ReFrames                : 3 frames
Codec ID                                 : avc1
Codec ID/Info                            : Advanced Video Coding
Duration                                 : 4mn 50s
Source duration                          : 1mn 35s
Nominal bit rate                         : 3 000 Kbps
Width                                    : 1 920 pixels
Height                                   : 1 080 pixels
Display aspect ratio                     : 16:9
Frame rate mode                          : Constant
Frame rate                               : 29.970 fps
Color space                              : YUV
Chroma subsampling                       : 4:2:0
Bit depth                                : 8 bits
Scan type                                : Progressive
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)                       : 0.048
Source stream size                       : 33.4 MiB (26%)
Writing library                          : x264 core 142 r2389 956c8d8
Encoding settings                        : cabac=1 / ref=1 / deblock=1:0:0 / analyse=0x1:0 / me=dia / subme=2 / psy=1 / psy_rd=1.00:0.00 / mixed_ref=0 / me_range=16 / chroma_me=1 / trellis=0 / 8x8dct=0 / cqm=0 / deadzone=21,11 / fast_pskip=1 / chroma_qp_offset=0 / threads=6 / lookahead_threads=2 / sliced_threads=0 / nr=0 / decimate=1 / interlaced=0 / bluray_compat=0 / constrained_intra=0 / bframes=3 / b_pyramid=1 / b_adapt=1 / b_bias=0 / direct=1 / weightb=1 / open_gop=0 / weightp=2 / keyint=250 / keyint_min=25 / scenecut=40 / intra_refresh=0 / rc_lookahead=40 / rc=abr / mbtree=1 / bitrate=3000 / ratetol=1.0 / qcomp=0.60 / qpmin=0 / qpmax=69 / qpstep=4 / ip_ratio=1.40 / aq=1:1.00
Language                                 : English
Tagged date                              : UTC 2016-06-10 15:32:15
```

As you can notice there are exactly "#" videos parts as "No suitable destination track found..." lines, which is strange. So far closest thing for fixing my problem is this command:

```
MP4Box -force-cat -add Awards\ -\ Recognitions\ Screens\ Video.mp4 -cat Cornaro\ USLUGE\ video1.mp4 -cat Cornaro\ USLUGE\ video1.mp4 -cat DIOCLETIANS_BREAKFAST.mp4 -cat FLAVOURS_OF_DALMATIA.mp4 -cat Prognoza.mp4 -cat Restaurants\ -\ Bars\ 2016.mp4 -cat WineHappyHour3.mp4 out.mp4
```

but it is showing second video (Cornaro USLUGE video1.mp4) two times in row and then rest is normal. I am really out of idea what to do. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for help but I need to use MP4Box to merge videos and not ffmpeg because I only have MP4Box installed on my RPi3.
Anyway, changed command and can confirm this works like charm (even if video is missing PAR param info):

```
MP4Box -force-cat -cat Awards\ -\ Recognitions\ Screens\ Video.mp4 -cat Cornaro\ USLUGE\ video1.mp4 -cat Cornaro\ USLUGE\ video1.mp4 -cat DIOCLETIANS_BREAKFAST.mp4 -cat FLAVOURS_OF_DALMATIA.mp4 -cat Prognoza.mp4 -cat Restaurants\ -\ Bars\ 2016.mp4 -cat WineHappyHour3.mp4 output.mp4
```

Comment: Be aware that for some reason output video won't loop with --loop param.

Answer (score 2):

This is a duplicate of https://github.com/gpac/gpac/issues/549 where this was answered: FFmpeg sometimes add the PAR optional field in the SPS. Thus MP4Box detects different SPS and cannot merge.

It is still under discussion whether GPAC should be able to detect this change as a workaround. Please express you opinion at the root issue: https://github.com/gpac/gpac/issues/13.

NB @IncBrain: bs-switching is a feature of DASH, not MP4.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `ffmpeg` to concatenate your mp4 files like described [here](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate#protocol):

First you have to transcode your videos to MPEG2-TS like this:

```
ffmpeg -i vid1.mp4 -c:v copy -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -f mpegts inter1.ts
ffmpeg -i vid2.mp4 -c:v copy -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -f mpegts inter2.ts
ffmpeg -i vid3.mp4 -c:v copy -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -f mpegts inter3.ts
...
```

And then concatenate them with:

```
ffmpeg -i "concat:inter1.ts|inter2.ts|inter3.ts" -c copy out.mp4
```

I tested it with [your videos](http://www.mediafire.com/download/aulvr1lpv6bu1o8/videos.zip) (link you posted on github) and it worked just fine.

There is also a possibility to do this without creation of intermediate .ts files using named pipes, this could look similar to this:

```
mkfifo temp1 temp2
ffmpeg -i input1.mp4 -c copy -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -f mpegts temp1 2> /dev/null & \
ffmpeg -i input2.mp4 -c copy -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -f mpegts temp2 2> /dev/null & \
ffmpeg -f mpegts -i "concat:temp1|temp2" -c copy output.mp4
```

Answer (score 0):

> but it is showing second video (Cornaro USLUGE video1.mp4) two times in row

It seems to me that you are adding it twice from the command-line.